# Jenkins, http management from docker

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have problems with jenkins-cli and I think I need help for debugging. 
My Jenkins installation runs from Docker, and I want to interact with it from within a different docker instance (so there's a jenkins/jenkins:lts docker instance and a jenkins-slave instance.)
When I try to connect to the master with http with the following command

`java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://<jenkins_url> -auth <user>:<pass> -http groovy myscript.groovy`

I got an error message as I can't use '-remoting' mode.

I am pretty sure this is connected to the https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-47279 issue, as "If you are running Jenkins behind an HTTP(S) reverse proxy, ensure it does not buffer request or response bodies." as seen in 
https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/cli/ but I am not sure how to debug it.

The funny thing is that I can use the Jenkins-job-builder tool from the same docker instance and that works with http.